# Instant Messaging feature for anonymous visitors to chat one on one with logged in users

Tags: php, mysql, chat, anonymous

My website is developed with PHP+MySQL. It allows users to login.

I need to include an Instant Messaging feature to allow anonymous visitors to the site to chat one on one with users of the site who are logged in.

- Users must not be able to chat with each other.
- The site should show a list of all users who are logged in and thus available for chat.
- Ability to keep track of how many times this is used would be useful, but not necessary.

Any ideas how this can be achieved? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ummm. "chat one on one" and "not be able to chat with each other" seems to be rather contradictory.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear enough. I want anonymous users to be able to chat one on one with the registered user of their choice. Registered users should not be able to chat with other registered users.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. First create a chat system of your choice(or find some open source
   chat system to fit your needs)
2. Show chat window fill with registered
   and logged in user for Anonymous user i-e If there session is not
   created then show up the logged in registered member. Generate a
   session with random number for the anonymous user to identify them.
3. For registered logged in user restrict the registered users to appear in chat window i-e users who are logged in with your Login
   Mechanism.
4. Always remember SO does't work this way. Start working on your project, Break down your problems into smaller parts and if you are
   having difficulty in executing some thing then come  and ask every
   one will help you.

I believe that you are looking for **Live Support System**. Where anonymous user user can chat with the representatives. Google them you get many and many of them are free one too.
Some of the good ones are----

```
http://www.comm100.com/livechat/
http://www.phplivesupport.com/
http://www.turnkeywebtools.com/phplivehelper/
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the chat in PHP.  Do it using Socket.io/jQuery.  It will be much easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Livezilla.

http://www.livezilla.net/home/en/

it accommodates everything you're asking for.
Andrew